# Stratified GroupShuffleSplit in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, shuffle, cross-validation

I would like to ask if it is possible to do "Stratified GroupShuffleSplit" in scikit-learn which is in other words a combination of [GroupShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit) and [StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
cv=GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=n_splits,test_size=test_size,\
    train_size=train_size,random_state=random_state).split(\
    allr_sets_nor[:,:2],allr_labels,groups=allr_groups)
opt=GridSearchCV(SVC(decision_function_shape=dfs,tol=tol),\
    param_grid=param_grid,scoring=scoring,n_jobs=n_jobs,cv=cv,verbose=verbose)
opt.fit(allr_sets_nor[:,:2],allr_labels)
```

Here I applied the `GroupShuffleSplit` but I still want to add the startification according to `allr_labels`

Comment: StratifiedShuffleSplit also has a parameter groups if you want. Just use Stratifiedshufflesplit will allr_labels and when fitting in GridSearchCV pass groups into fit() method

Comment: It didn't work for me unfortunately, I think that this option is inactive as it is said in the documentation "Always ignored, exists for compatibility.
"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by applying StratifiedShuffleSplit on the groups and then finding training and testing sets indices manually because they are linked to the groups indices (in my case each group contains 6 successive sets from `6*index` to `6*index+5`)

as in the following:

```
sss=StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=n_splits,test_size=test_size,
    train_size=train_size,random_state=random_state).split(all_groups,all_labels) 
        # startified splitting for groups only

i=0
train_is = [np.array([],dtype=int)]*n_splits
test_is = [np.array([],dtype=int)]*n_splits
for train_index,test_index in sss :
        # finding the corresponding indices of reflected training and testing sets
    train_is[i]=np.hstack((train_is[i],np.concatenate([train_index*6+i for i in range(6)])))
    test_is[i]=np.hstack((test_is[i],np.concatenate([test_index*6+i for i in range(6)])))
    i=i+1

cv=[(train_is[i],test_is[i]) for i in range(n_splits)]
        # constructing the final cross-validation iterable: list of 'n_splits' tuples;
        # each tuple contains two numpy arrays for training and testing indices respectively

opt=GridSearchCV(SVC(decision_function_shape=dfs,tol=tol),param_grid=param_grid,
                 scoring=scoring,n_jobs=n_jobs,cv=cv,verbose=verbose)
opt.fit(allr_sets_nor[:,:2],allr_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is supported by scikit-learn now with [`StratifiedGroupKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold)